# Missing ; after for-loop initializer... again

Tags: loops, for-loop, syntax

ERR:Missing ; after for-loop initializer. (line 3, file "Tst")

This is a copy/paste of the code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for (int i = 0; i < ss.getNumberOfSheets(); i++){
    Sheet sheet = ss.getSheetAt(i);
    Logger.log(sheet.getName());
  }
}
```

I don't see any missing semicolons ???

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: Assuming this is Javascript, because it's obviously not Java, replace the `int` with `var`. You don't specify a type when declaring a JS variable.

Answer (score -1):

What if you replace int with var or even just remove the declaration of i? Looks like JavaScript, is it?

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for (i = 0; i < ss.getNumberOfSheets(); i++){
    Sheet sheet = ss.getSheetAt(i);
    Logger.log(sheet.getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't make answers for things like this. If you have a question, use a comment.

Comment: Sorry, yes Java of sorts. Its a Google sheets macro.

Comment: @chuckt62 Do you mean Javascript? That's a very different language fro. Java